# Is there a way to trigger update views right after CRUD operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, elasticsearch

I'm having a simple CRUD app. When I make ajax call to delete (for example) a document, then I want to update the view with the new document list.

I've tried to use ajaxStop / ajaxSuccess and setTimeout. SetTimeout works well, but the result I'm looking for is without the timeout. With ajaxStop / ajaxSuccess, sometimes the view is updated.

```
const getAllDocument = () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/elastic/index/person',
            method: 'POST',
            global: false
        }).done(function(data){
                $("#personTable").empty();
                dataLength = data.length;
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#personTable").append(data) // Just example
                }
        }).fail(function(err){
                console.log(err);
        });
    }

$('#confirmDelete').on('click', function () {
        let docType = $("#personTypeDelete").html();
        let _id = $("#personIdDelete").html();
        let data = {
            docType: docType,
            _id: _id
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/delete',
            method: 'DELETE',
            data: data

        }).done(function(data) {
            toastr.success("Delete person succeed!", '', toastOption);
            getAllDocument();
        }).fail(function(err) {
            toastr.error("Delete person failed!", '', toastOption);
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

I expect the personTable to be updated with new person list exclude the deleted document right after it was deleted.
Is there any method or keyword can help me solve this problem?

Comment: I think you have an asynchronous issue in the controller action that handles the `/delete` route; you are returning a success before the document has been deleted from elastic.

Comment: I found out that elasticsearch marked a document as "deleted", but it can be alive for a little time more. I think i need to search more about When a document is really deleted in elasticsearch, and How to know when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Refresh`:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

```
The Index, Update, Delete, and Bulk APIs support setting refresh to control 
when changes made by this request are made visible to search.
```

But this is not the recommended way to use Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch is not a realtime database, but a near-realtime database. Forcing refresh in a huge clusters in Elasticsearch is never a good idea.

So use this if you know what you are doing =)

Comment: Many thanks. With this, I can achieve what i want, for now. This works well in small clusters like mine.